# Python import error even though relevant module is installed

Tags: python, importerror, urllib3, python-behave

I'm trying to run Python behave tests but get the following error:

```
[moadmin@modevvm12 e2e-tests]$ behave -i features/tests/connmgr_2_scan_management_container.feature 
Exception ImportError: No module named request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/behave", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 183, in main
    return run_behave(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 127, in run_behave
    failed = runner.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 804, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 808, in run_with_paths
    self.load_hooks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 784, in load_hooks
    exec_file(hooks_path, self.hooks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/behave/runner_util.py", line 386, in exec_file
    exec(code, globals_, locals_)
  File "features/environment.py", line 20, in <module>
    from framework.sd.api.auth_rbac import AuthRBAC
  File "/tmp/e2e-tests/framework/sd/api/auth_rbac.py", line 10, in <module>
    from framework.sd.api.sd_endpoint import SDEndpoint
  File "/tmp/e2e-tests/framework/sd/api/sd_endpoint.py", line 12, in <module>
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ImportError: No module named request
```

urllib is installed so I can't understand why I get this error.

Comment: how are you importing request?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but is request not used by urllib3?

Comment: You've probably already looked, but does this page help? https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

Comment: Are you running with the correct Python version?